# Let $K = \{f \in \mathcal F \mid f \text{ is constant function}\}$, prove that $K$ is the equivalence class.

Tags: functions, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

> $$\mathcal F = \{f \mid f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R\}$$
>
> $$R = \{(f,g) \mid \exists h \in \mathcal F (f = h \circ g )\}$$
>
> $$S = R \cap R^{-1}$$
>
> $$[f]_S = \{h : hSf\}$$
>
> $$F/S = \{[f]_S \mid f \in \mathcal F\}$$
>
> $K = \{f \in \mathcal F \mid f \text{ is constant function}\}$
>
> **Prove that $K \in F/S$.**

My attempt:

Take arbitrary two constant functions in $\mathcal F$, say $g,f$

Let $$g(x) = c_1$$

and

$$f(x) = c_2$$

Let $h \in \mathcal F$ and $h(c_2) = c_1$

Then we have

$$g = h \circ f$$

Now let $h \in \mathcal F$ and $h(c_1) = c_2$, then

$$f = h \circ g$$

Hence $fRg$, $gRs$, and therefore $fSg$ $gSf$

Now let $g$ be constant function such that for all $x$, $g(x) = c_1$ and let $f$ be non-constant function.

We have $gRf$, but clearly $(f,g) \notin R$, and thus $(f,g)$ and $(g,f)$ are not in $S$.

Hence for arbitrary constant function $f \in \mathcal F$,  $[f]_S$ will be the set that consists of all constant functions in $\mathcal F$. Since $[f]_S = K$, we have $K \in F/S$

$\Box$.

Is it correct?

Comment: "Prove that $K$ are in $F/S$." Can you please explain what this sentence means?

Comment: @OlivierRoche I meant "Prove that $K$ **is** in $F/S$", or $K \in F/S$

Comment: OK, replace $q$ with $f$ and the proof is correct.

Comment: @OlivierRoche I made an edit. Thanks for the review!

Answer (score 1):

> We have $gRf$, but clearly $(f,g) \notin R$

That sentence requires more explanation.

So you got one thing right: any two constant functions are related.

All you need now is to prove that a non-constant function is never related to a constant function. And this follows from the simple observation that a composition of any function with a constant function (regardless of order) is again constant. Therefore if $f$ is non-constant and $g$ is constant then $(f,g)\not\in R$ by the definition of $R$.

Comment: Probably you meant $gRf$ is short for $(g,f) \in R$ but not $(f,g) \in R$? I agree that concluding "$gRf$, but $(f,g) \notin R$" (which is equivalent to "$(g,f) \in R$, but $(f,g) \notin R$") without any explanation might be a bit abrupt, but I don't understand why the sentence doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Nelver oh, right, I misread the order. Updated.

Comment: ;@Nelver What you claimed is correct : one has $gRf$ but not $fRg$