# Let $K = \{f \in \mathcal F \mid f \text{ is constant function}\}$, prove that $K$ is the smallest element of $F/S$ in the partial order $T$.

Tags: functions, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

> $$\mathcal F = \{f \mid f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R\}$$
>
> $$R = \{(f,g) \mid \exists h \in \mathcal F (f = h \circ g )\}$$
>
> $$S = R \cap R^{-1}$$
>
> $$[f]_S = \{h : hSf\}$$
>
> $$F/S = \{[f]_S \mid f \in \mathcal F\}$$
> $T \subseteq \mathcal F / S \times
>  F / S$, such that for all $f,g \in \mathcal F$, $[f]_ST[g]_S$ iff
> $fRg$, and $T$ is a partial order on $\mathcal F /S$.
>
> $K = \{f \in \mathcal F \mid f \text{ is constant function}\}$
>
> **Prove that $K$ is the smallest element of $\mathcal F/S$ in the partial
> order $T$.**

My attempt:

What we know

1. S is an equivalence relation on $\mathcal F$
2. $\mathcal F/S$ is a partition (Follows from the fact that $S$ is an equivalence relation)
3. $K \in F/S$ (I tried to show it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3431024/let-k-f-in-mathcal-f-mid-f-text-is-constant-function-prove-that))

Now take $X \in F/S$. Take $f \in K$ and $g \in X$.

We know that $f$ is a constant function, thus  $f = f \circ g$ and $fRg$.

Since $f,g$ were arbitrary, we conclude that for all $f \in K$ and for all $g \in X$, $fRg$. Hence $(K,X) \in T$.

Since $X$ was arbitrary, we have

$$\forall X \in F/S\bigl((K,X) \in T\bigr)$$

Thus $K$ is the smallest element of $F/S$.

$\Box$

Is it correct?

Comment: Your proof looks OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument is correct, but you might be interested to know the general context of your question. Your relations $R$ and $S$ are instances of [Green's relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_relations) on a [monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid). Indeed, if $M$ is a multiplicative monoid, you can define the following relations on $M$:
\begin{align}
f \leqslant_\cal{L} g &\quad\text{if there exists $h \in M$ such that $f = hg$}\\ 
f \mathrel{\cal{L}} g &\quad\text{if and only if $f \leqslant_\cal{L} g$ and $g \leqslant_\cal{L} f$.}
\end{align}
The symbol $\cal L$ refers to *left*, since we use left multiplication. There are dual relations for right multiplication, denoted $\leqslant_\cal{R}$ and $\cal R$.

Now, back to your question. Here you consider the monoid of functions from $\Bbb R$ to itself under the composition of functions. The relation $R$ is $\leqslant_\cal{L}$ and $S$ is $\cal L$. And indeed, the constant functions are minimal in the preorder $\leqslant_\cal{L}$, as you proved it.